# Angular2 directive listen to parent component callbacks or changes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-directive, angular-components

I have an angular2/4 directive that I made, that I attach to input DOM elements, which adds a class to them, marking that they are not empty.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[inputNotEmptyAddClass]'
})
export class InputNotEmptyDirective implements OnInit {
...
@HostListener('change') onChange() {
        this.process();
    }
...
process() {
[Add class to parent input element, when it has a value]
}
```

It was all working fine, until I introduced a datepicker module (https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) to the show. This module creates a new component, in which one of the children is an input and the whole thing lets me pick a date.

What I am trying to achieve here:

I want to rewrite my directive to listen in on either the date picker's callbacks or subscribe (I am using RXjS) to some of the datepickers variables. Yet I am out of ideas on how to implement this correctly.

What I have tried?

I have discovered that using the ControlValueAccessor

```
constructor( @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) private _valueAccessor: ControlValueAccessor )
```

I can check and see, if the element my directive is hooked into is the date picker.

```
if ( this._valueAccessor[0].constructor.name == 'MyDatePicker' ) {
```

Now I can see that it has onChange functions and all the variables, but I have no idea how to subscribe to them.

I could also use the modules callback functions in my directive, but they seem not to be triggering. Is there any way to make them trigger?

```
onDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {
        // event properties are: event.date, event.jsdate, event.formatted and event.epoc
    }
```

Bottom line.

I am open to any clues or solutions about how to hook a directive into the parent elements variables and callbacks. I understand that this is a pretty generic question, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: am sorry , can you tell in one line what you want . What do you want to do on events of data picker

Comment: A directive connects to a DOM element or some component. I want to be able to subscribe to attribute changes on that element or component OR be able to hook into the callbacks on that component.

Comment: Did you try `@HostListener('dateChanged')` ?

Comment: Thank you! It was as simple as that. Somehow I did not come upon this solution. I thought the callbacks were made on a specific function if it existed, not triggering an event. I could mark you as an answer if you create one. Do you also happen to know if I can also subscribe to value changes on an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the event dispatched by the input . In case of date its `dateChanged` , in case of regular input its `change` .

Without the directive you can just say

```
<input type="text" (change)="doSomething()" />

// (dateChanged)="doSomething()" in case of date
```

If you are having it in a directive, you can add `HostListener` to it.

```
@HostListener('dateChanged') dateChange() {
     //  do something  
}
```

Comment: Since I can ask for improvements, I would like to know if a directive can subscribe to changes on it's parent DOM elements attributes? Is this also possible and maybe you can also leave a line about it in your answer. This would be helpful knowledge indeed.